# Here map drawing a route from A to B and displaying it even if the start point is in a building

Tags: here-api

As you can see the path below isn't totally complete.
I would like the path to be drawn from the start point (and not from the closest point in street).

Does anyone know if there is a way with heremap to draw this part ? Or is this just simple not possible ?

I've looked here without success: https://developer.here.com

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is to use the navigation position of the POI instead of the centroid location of the POI. By default the position returned of a place is the "center" of the building location, not the entrance location.

The solution:
Place the marker using [Location#getAccessPoints()](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-search-location.html#topic-apiref__getaccesspoints-void) API

For indoor related usage, please also integrate with the 3d Venue APIs to add indoor routing to the app.